# What better way to use CSS / JS in Laravel and where to put it?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

What do I call style files? Are there good practices? Laravel v.5.4

Comment: you need to put all your css and js in public folder . and access the public folder in view like this {{ asset('folder/jquery.js') }}

Comment: Javascript files, CSS files and Image files that make the frontend of your site are called assets. In laravel they are under public folder. The best practices may vary as per the intention like do you want to minimize them, merge them...the list is long..

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel mix to compile your all css and js if you have node installed, for that you have to put your css and js in `resources/assets folder`.

You have to install node dependencies by running `npm install` in your laravel folder.

For compiling your js and css you can use

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js'], 'public/js');

mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/style.css',
    'resources/assets/css/style1.css'
], 'public/css/all.css');
```

in `webpack.mix.js` file, it will compile all your css and js to public folder  into single css/js file.

you can use `npm run dev` to compile your files or `npm run watch` to add watcher when your js/css files change

more reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix)

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
{!! Html::script(asset('js/app.js?v=12')) !!}
```

and

```
{!! Html::style(asset('css/app.css')) !!}
```

I think this is short code.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.